# Oracle Report layout issue?

Tags: plsql, report, oracle9i

I am a novice user of Oracle Report Builder, so forgive me if the answer should be obvious.

I am attempting to run a 9i report, and I keep getting an error that appears like there is an issue with frames overlapping.  I have two versions and both are getting the same error.  One version is the report I want. The other is a stripped down version with only a couple fields, to narrow down what might be causing it.

```
Terminated with error: <br>REP-271187990: Virtual Memory System error. REP-0200: Cannot allocate enough memory. cavaa 22 REP-0002: Unable to retrieve a string from the Report Builder message file. REP-271187990:
```

Occasionally, it kicks out the message below when I try to run it, with no other accompanying details.  The select runs and returns the desired results, and the function returns the ref cursor results as expected.  The package is valid and compiled, so the query itself should be fine. There is only one query in the report, and I have tried various things, including stripping the report to narrow down the source of the error, with no luck.  Any ideas to try would be appreciated.

```
Terminated with error: <br>REP-1401: 'qr_1refcurds1': Fatal PL/SQL error occurred.
```

Comment: I have over 4 Gb Virtual Memory allocated, and there are less than 50 records returned... so I can't imagine this being a memory issue.

Comment: It was suggested that perhaps the refcursor was returning data of a wrong type, but my refcursor are all defined in the spec in the <table>.<field>%type format.

Comment: OK... I think I have this narrowed down.  It seems to be the repeating frame that is offensive.  Now to figure out which property to tweak.  Ideas?  (I am assuming I need to use a repeating frame vs. a regular frame).

Comment: Looks like it could be bad data.  Grr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with data returned from my refcursor.

In the package spec I had one of the fields wrong field in the table.field%type declaration.

For those experiencing a similar error I would suggest:

1. If you have your SQL in functions, as opposed to right in the report, check your package spec to ensure your field order matches usage in the body.
2. If you have any overlapping frames in your report, this message can also come up.  Check the object navigator for any hidden frames.  They can be totally invisible, and the only way to know for sure is by checking in the navigator.  Hint - Give meaningful names to your fields and text labels, so you can see what's contained in each frame.  Also check the source of container frames is... but that's another REP error to enjoy.
3. Depending on setup, the first time you load a report it may error out referring to one of your queries.  That happens after compile.  Just try again, and every time going forward it's fine.
4. Consider the server patches mentioned above if your SQL statements are dynamic.

Feel free to add to this list if you know of others.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle Support](http://support.oracle.com) Note 430044.1 -

> MS Windows: Reports 10g with Ref Cursors Fails with REP-200 and REP-65
>   Virtual Memory System Error [ID 430044.1]
>
> This is a known Oracle Reports bug for MS Windows Platform.
>
> Bug 5584001 DYNAMIC REF CURSORS DON'T WORK IN VERSION 10.1.2.0.2
>   REPORTS BUILDER

There are step by step instructions in the Oracle Note to apply the patch to resolve this issue. Also note, this problem is specific to MS Windows.

The suggested Oracle One-off patches are-

- One-off patch [4505133](https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=4505133)
- One-off patch [5634746](https://updates.oracle.com/ARULink/PatchDetails/process_form?patch_num=5634746)

Log-on to Oracle Support, download the two patches and follow the step by step instructions mentioned in `Note 430044.1` to apply the patch.

Comment: I read this too.  I am using a stongly-typed static refcursor, and not a dynamic refcursor.  All our other reports are using similar refcursors as well.

Comment: There are some conflicting reports of this `error` occurring even if the ref-cursor is strongly-typed. Check if you already have the patch, if not apply it. Also check if there are any other ref-cursors in the report that may be dynamic. If none helps then I think you should go ahead and log an SR with oracle.

Comment: I believe the fact that all the other reports are working with ref cursors indicates this has to do with this particular report, and/or the patch has already been applied, or doesn't need to be.  Only 1 refcursor.  I think I have narrowed it down to the repeating frame being the offender... still working on what will rectify.  If I don't get this thing working I will look at contacting Oracle.